# View containing navigation bar and tab bar is shifted some 4mm downwards

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

In my app from a login screen I am navigating to a class say classA, like this:

```
classA *objUserHome = [[classA alloc]init];
        [self presentModalViewController:objUserHome animated:YES];
        [objUserHome release];
```

And ClassA is having a navigating bar and a tabbar (5 tabs in it), I have created my tab bar programmatically like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //Create tab bar controller and navigation bar controller
    
    tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    
    NSMutableArray *arrControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5];
    
    //Add PunchClock to tab View Controller
    PunchClock* objPunchClock = [[PunchClock alloc] initWithTabBar];
    NavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:objPunchClock];
    NavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor brownColor];
    [arrControllers addObject:NavigationController];
    [NavigationController release];
    [objPunchClock release];
    
    //Add Time_Sheet to tab View Controller
    Time_Sheet* objTime_Sheet = [[Time_Sheet alloc] initWithTabBar];
    NavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:objTime_Sheet];
    NavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor brownColor];
    [arrControllers addObject:NavigationController];
    [NavigationController release];
    [objTime_Sheet release];
    
    //Add PTO to tab View Controller
    PTO* objPTO = [[PTO alloc] initWithTabBar];
    NavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:objPTO];
    NavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor brownColor];
    [arrControllers addObject:NavigationController];
    [NavigationController release];
    [objPTO release];
    
    //Add PunchClock to tab View Controller
    CrewPunch* objCrewPunch = [[CrewPunch alloc] initWithTabBar];
    NavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:objCrewPunch];
    NavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor brownColor];
    [arrControllers addObject:NavigationController];
    [NavigationController release];
    [objCrewPunch release];
    
    //Add PunchClock to tab View Controller
    Reports* objReports = [[Reports alloc] initWithTabBar];
    NavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:objReports];
    NavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor brownColor];
    [arrControllers addObject:NavigationController];
    [NavigationController release];
    [objReports release];
    
    // Add this view controller array into the tab bar
    
    //self .viewControllers = arrControllers;
     tabBarController .viewControllers = arrControllers;
   
    [arrControllers release];
    [self.view addSubview:[tabBarController view]];
    
   
}
```

And `ClassA is inherited from  UIViewController`

Now the problem is, after navigating to  classA, view of classA is shifted some 4mm  downwards per the image below. Why is it so? How can I fix this?

[image: like this]

Comment: Have you used interface builder? (for the view, not the tab-bar specifically) as the view might be set too small?

Comment: @nbsp   No,i have not used XIB,  Programatically i have created the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long research i finally fixed this issue just by inheriting the class from `UINavigationController` instead of `UIViewControler`

Answer (score 1):

When using storyboards and `Modal Transition` between 2 or more views you can encounter an error similar to the above.

If you use `Modal Transition` from `ViewControllerA` to `ViewControllerZ` and then attempt to `Modal Transition` from `ViewControllerZ` back to `ViewControllerA` sometimes the view of `ViewControllerA` gets pushed down the Window slightly.

This can be prevented using:

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

On `ViewControllerZ` to go back to `ViewControllerA` from an event on `ViewControllerZ`

Comment: you opening paragraph is confusing

Answer (score 0):

You might have chosen some top bar in your Interface Builder or XIB file and additionally set the navigation bar. Dont choose any top bar in the XIB file.

Answer (score 0):

Try as below

```
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:[tabBarController view]];
```

Comment: its giving a blank screen ,,view contents are invisible